# Qt Table model to Tree model

Tags: c++, qt, qsqltablemodel

In Qt I have a sqlite database which I'm pulling in. One of the tables (configTable) has a `QSqlTableModel` attached.

The table has a simple 2-column key/value structure. The keys are strings with folder-like values such as "general/name", "general/version", "foo/bar/baz", etc. Values are just arbitrary variants.

I'd like to display this data in an easier-to-browse `QTreeView` instead of a `QTableView`, as my key structure lends itself very nicely to that.

Before I go reimplementing classes and all sorts of crazy things - is there an elegant solution to this? And if I reimplement or extend classes, which ones should I look at?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the parsing+mapping between the list of `value/value/value` and a tree model yourself. But there is a (tricky) Qt way to do this yes.

The [Qt Model-View architecture](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) can represent many different structures of data, based on the [`QAbstractItemModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#details) class. A Qt model must implement some functions to tell the view : how many columns, row, children etc.

---

A list model (Qt provides [`QAbstractListModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html#details)), is basically a model that says to the view :

- I have one root item (all data items are represented by a [`QModelIndex`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#details), root has an invalid parent)
- This root item has only one column
- This root item has as many rows as your list has elements

A tree model will return the appropriate children for each `QModelIndex`. The abstract model of Qt actually allows each child item to be a table (`QModelIndex` always has a parent **and** a row-column index).

---

Long story short, you have to create a proxy model ([`QAbstractProxyModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractproxymodel.html#details) or a suitable subclass, but for your need I don't think there is one). This proxy will transform the data your `QSqlTableModel` is sending, and this is where you can tell the view that you actually have a tree and not a list.

Your root items are the items from your database list of keys (first element of the `foo/bar/whatever`), but you need to regroup all the root items that has the same key.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK you can make it only manually.

Basically, because how did you think Qt knows how to convert your data into tree model.